# I wanted to give an Id for all the child elements in the div that are created dynamically using the information stored in that JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, dom

The code I wrote is only giving the Id for the first element.

```
function addClass() {
  csrdLst = document.querySelector('.card-')
  for (let j = 0; j <= works.length; j++) {
  csrdLst.setAttribute('id', `main-project${j}`);
  }
}
addClass();
```

this is the code I used.

Comment: `csrdLst = document.querySelectorAll('.card-')` to get all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use `querySelectorAll` method to fetch all elements in an array structure.

```
function addClass() {
  csrdLst = document.querySelectorAll('.card-')
  for (let j = 0; j <= works.length; j++) {
    csrdLst[j].setAttribute('id', `main-project${j}`);
  }
}
addClass();
```

Comment: Glad it worked. You can upvote and mark it as accepted the answer if this solves your problem.